# css media query margin-top element div

Tags: css, media-queries, margin

I have the following javascript . I want to change the margin-top and margin-left of a div element. I use this media query

```css
@media screen and (max-width:1024px) {
  .my-list {
    margin-top: 120px;
    margin-left: 350px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="my-list">
  test message
</div>
```

The final screen is

[image]

How can I change margin-top and margin-left of a div element?

Comment: Javascript? Where is it?

Comment: Can you add more information want to want? And where is the javascript ?

Comment: what do you want please describe your questions

Answer (score 0):

> I want to change the margin-top and margin-left of a div element

What you have done is correct. Now it depends on your requirement. According to your media query, it will apply css for all resolution screen less than 1024px.

Because you have applied: `max-width:1024px` in your media query. Now if you want to set higher than 1024 then you can use `'min-width: 1024px'`.

Check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/c97azpv9/) fiddle. That works